# how do i set button to run macros in vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do i set a button to run my program, what i wanna do, i don't want my this workbook to run when i open up a my workbook, i create a button and i want my button to run macros when i click it and if i don't click it then my macros should not run and my workbook should stay it is, its kind a like enable macros content or disable content but want to do it with button

```
         sub button_click()
         application.enableevents = false

         application.enableevents = true
         end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoukd do a little more research before posting  question. This link details how to add a button and assign a macro to it in excel vba.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx

Comment: i think you should read the question first before you even answer it, thats not what im looking for and i do know how to add a button n make it work i just don't know how to activate this workbook with a button